# Volley Request - No Response if URL is wrong, How to detect this scenario in volley request?

Tags: android, request, android-volley

Hello I am trying to download some images from URLs returned from a JSON but if such request URLs are wrong I am not getting any response from volley request and it just get stuck there for a very very long time.  I have included a sample code block below. FetchImage method is called in a loop but from the request where there is URL is wrong there is no response in onResponse or onError block and I am not able to detect whether process has ended.

```
    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
String url = Constants.API_BASE_URL

FetchImage(url, queue);

private void FetchImage(String url, RequestQueue queue) {
    //get image file name
    final String imageFile = utils.getFileNameFromPath(url);

    final File imgDIR = new File(systemCardSavePath);
    if(!imgDIR.exists()){
        imgDIR.mkdirs();
    }

    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    try{
                        File file = new File(imgDIR, imageFile);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytearrayoutputstream);
                        fileoutputstream.write(bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray());
                        fileoutputstream.close();
                        cardData.put(imageFile, "1");

                        requestsCounter.decrementAndGet();
                        if (requestsCounter.get() == 0) {
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

                    }catch (FileNotFoundException exFNFE){
                        exFNFE.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (IOException exIO){
                        exIO.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //do error handling
        }
    });

    queue.add(imageRequest);
    requestsCounter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the url is wrong or incorrect url format or it even doesn't exist, then we will get  BadUrl Exception. Then handle the error by passing some message. Its our duty to give correct url. This is developer's mistake. This doesn't concerns the user.

Answer (score 0):

To handle different types of error we need to do proper error handling for volley as below (sequence of error handling also important):

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        } else if(error instanceof ClientError) {
    //404 error can be further traced under ClientError section
                         if(((NetworkResponse) ((ClientError)error).networkResponse).statusCode == 404){
                         }
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        }
                    }
                }
```